# UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve in iOS 5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

Can any one give me an example showing crossdissolve effect using `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` for two images.

I searched a lot but I couldn't find any good examples.

Can I get some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is test, create two UIImageView and overlap them also create an array of images name, then use the following action for the next (tag = 1) and previous (tag = 0) buttons that will switch between images:

```
- (void) switchImagesHandler:(int *)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch (btn.tag) {
    case 0:
        if (currentImg != 0) {
            currentImg--;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                [firstImage setAlpha:0];
            }];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                [firstImage setAlpha:1];
                [firstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:currentImg]]];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [secondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:currentImg]]];
            }];
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (currentImg != [imagesArray count]) {
            currentImg++;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                [firstImage setAlpha:0];
            }];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                [firstImage setAlpha:1];
                [firstImage setImage:[UIImage imageNameds:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:currentImg]]];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [secondImage setImage:[UIImage imageNameds:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:currentImg]]];
            }];
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i cannot see any transition from first imageview to seccond image view